# django fabric define multiple host with password

Tags: django, fabric

Lets say I have a list of hosts to provide:

```
env.hosts = ['host1', 'host2', 'host3']
env.password = ['password1', 'password2', 'password3']
```

Its not working for me.. I dont just want to give host and give password for everyhost. I want to set the password for every host and it should get the password and deploy my site without asking for password.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Your best options is to do this:

Note: that the password keys need to be `user`@`location`:`port` otherwise it wont work.

fabfile.py

```
from fabric.api import env, task, run

@task
def environments():
    env.hosts = ['user1@10.99.0.2', 'user2@10.99.0.2', 'user3@10.99.0.2']
    env.passwords = {'user1@10.99.0.2:22': 'pass1', 'user2@10.99.0.2:22': 'pass2', 'user3@10.99.0.2:22': 'pass3'}


@task
def echo():
    run('whoami')
```

and then to test:

```
$ fab environments echo
[user1@10.99.0.2] Executing task 'echo'
[user1@10.99.0.2] run: whoami
[user1@10.99.0.2] out: user1
[user1@10.99.0.2] out: 

[user2@10.99.0.2] Executing task 'echo'
[user2@10.99.0.2] run: whoami
[user2@10.99.0.2] out: user2
[user2@10.99.0.2] out: 

[user3@10.99.0.2] Executing task 'echo'
[user3@10.99.0.2] run: whoami
[user3@10.99.0.2] out: user3
[user3@10.99.0.2] out: 


Done.
Disconnecting from user2@10.99.0.2... done.
Disconnecting from user1@10.99.0.2... done.
Disconnecting from user3@10.99.0.2... done.
```